# conversion from NSTimeInterval to days

Tags: swift, xcode, nstimeinterval

I have a date1 and the current Date when the view did load.
Now I want to display how many days have passed since the day.

let timeInterval = date1.timeIntervalSince(date2)

Now I want to convert the timeInterval in days.
Anyone could help?

Answer (score 11):

Rather than using TimeInterval you can get the number of days directly by using the Calendar class and DateComponents

```
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
print(days.day!)
```